# Unordered menu items unable to be clicked

Tags: html, css, menu

This is an annoying one, and really sorry as I expect it might be quite simple, but I've searched and searched and everything I get is nothing like what my problem is.

I'm making a menu bar using an unordered HTML list, but the first three items of my list do not work. I can't click them and hovering doesn't fire the a:hover highlight. The other three do work. I've gone over my HTML and CSS but I'm not sure what is wrong.

My code is as follows;

```css
html { }

body { 
 font-family: Georgia, Times, Arial;
 background: #fff; 
}

.container { 
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 float: left; 
}

.menu {
 float: left; 
 clear: left;
 width: 100%;
 background: #cfcfcf; 
 overflow:hidden; 
}

.content { 
 width: 100%;
 float: left; 
 right: 9%; 
 position:relative;
 }

.menuProper { 
 width: 22%; 
 position: relative;
 font-weight: bold;
 float: left; 
 background: #fff; 
 height: 100%; 
 left: 15%;
}

.logoProper { 
 width: 375px; 
 height: 269px; 
 background: url("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/172663886/Community%20Club%20Logo.png");
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.contentProper { 
 width: 75%; 
  left: 16%; 
 position: relative;
}

h1 {
 font-size: 40px; 
 font-weight: bold; 
}

h2 { 
 font-size: 35px;
}
h3 { 
 font-size: 30px; 
}

ul#nav { 
 list-style: none; 
 list-style-type: none; 
}

ul#nav a { 
 text-decoration: none; 
 padding: 3%; 
 color: #000;
 font-size: 30px; 
 line-height: 50px;
}

ul#nav a:hover { 
 background: #e9def6; 
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Tasmanian Community Poultry Society - Home</title>
<meta name="description" content="The Tasmanian Community Poultry Society is a group of poultry keepers working together to learn new skills, assist each other and connect the poultry community."/>
<meta name="keywords" content="poultry, community, tasmania, society, club, local organisation"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"/>
<head profile="http://www.w3.org/2005/10/profile"/>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">

<div class="logo">

<div class="content">
<div class="menu">



<div class="menuProper">
<div class="logoProper"></div>
<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="">Meetings</a></li>
<li><a href="">Online Community</a></li>
<li><a href="">Advice & Info</a></li>
<li><a href="">Etc</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="contentProper">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, a tortor id taciti vel purus augue, ac vel donec vestibulum phasellus, eu sagittis venenatis turpis quis enim, luctus sed, laoreet ullamcorper. Amet dapibus faucibus purus nonummy ac, vitae et pede. Duis magna tincidunt lacus vitae magna, vitae malesuada. Ipsum elementum metus, sed orci lectus, suspendisse scelerisque commodo nec quis vulputate. Wisi id ullamcorper voluptatem lacus et dictumst, lectus class non, metus eu, ullamcorper ut sollicitudin orci enim erat, magna mollis hymenaeos gravida nunc diam. Volutpat quis consectetuer tellus elit, ac pretium. Turpis vitae metus id nullam sem, laboris aliquam lectus omnis at tellus. Vestibulum eget elit placerat, elit pretium ultricies at neque orci, dolor vel etiam felis nullam sed, ac nunc dapibus mi tellus nulla.</p>
<p>Potenti duis duis sed sapien. Imperdiet orci enim venenatis sodales, suspendisse sem sed pulvinar proin ultrices nunc, est vivamus quam tempus fusce urna, sed nisl lacus vitae, mauris condimentum mi mi vehicula. Leo orci erat turpis penatibus ridiculus, massa quisque convallis sit, sollicitudin velit enim sagittis posuere dolor, rutrum egestas mi ultricies. Ligula nibh neque, erat varius tincidunt quam morbi ipsum wisi. Luctus felis, condimentum odio dui nullam.</p>
<p>Praesent faucibus. Malesuada neque viverra velit lacus, auctor dolor, placerat vel maecenas ultricies et morbi ad. Libero tristique mauris etiam eros in, fermentum etiam amet ut, nec laoreet viverra, nibh libero posuere magna, tincidunt cras et sodales arcu ut. Tincidunt phasellus integer, egestas quis erat eu, lorem nec sapien hendrerit ullamcorper euismod aliquet, porttitor vestibulum in diam vitae varius, quis nihil metus maecenas ut. Et luctus egestas lacinia aliquam, posuere accumsan blandit, diam amet pede turpis laoreet pede vitae. Sollicitudin et, donec lacus, quis vel, mus natoque sed in adipiscing gravida tincidunt, tristique mauris semper in. Vivamus officia mauris lorem velit curabitur, fringilla semper nulla donec vitae in.</p>
<p>Vel non, amet vestibulum elit mauris nulla a dolor, eget aliquet maecenas, augue nascetur eu. Tincidunt suspendisse sed et sit fringilla, consequat vestibulum viverra, erat vel venenatis at nec. Eu ornare sit. Suspendisse sodales, curabitur sociosqu donec malesuada, velit mattis nisi quis vivamus, laoreet congue. Sodales sed enim, eos sit velit, pede euismod in rhoncus justo pede metus, sagittis auctor, egestas rutrum at. Faucibus duis fusce bibendum purus, pharetra arcu. Libero maecenas at ante, dictum sapien sem eget, quis a pellentesque maecenas justo dui.</p>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your intention for the page is, but it is not actually the first 3 items -- it's that on *your* monitor.  The items are being covered by the `p` tag content because you've floated the navigation.  That's why the image is overlaying the text at the top, too, on smaller monitors.

Comment: @JeremyMiller - Oops. Didn't realise that because I'm using such a large monitor. I was trying to make it dynamic sizing, but the logo has messed things up for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add some `z-index` to `class` `menuProper`

Your `div` are overlapping each other. `contentProper` overlaps `menuProper` so some of the links are not clickable.

I added `z-index: 100;` and it works for me.

Comment: thanks @mr-alien for the formatting. @kingborough You should rethink your HTML design `logo` is parent div for `content`

Comment: Thanks. That works perfectly. I also managed to fix the text overlap with the image by making its sizing dynamic, so all perfect! Thank you so much. I knew it'd be something caused by my stupidity.

Comment: Sorry, new to here, didn't realise how to do it.

Comment: have you tried Bootstrap. You can learn HTML, CSS by looking at bootstrap implementation http://getbootstrap.com

Comment: web designing with bootstrap is done with Grid system usually 12 or 18 columns in a grid. So your menu could have been 3 columns while other content could have been remaining 9 columns(out of 12).

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with your class .contentProper. Give style like follow

```
.contentProper{
    float:left; // Add float.
    width:60%; // decrease the width as you want. for me 60% is working in my screen.
    position:relative;
    left:16%;
}
```